# Laravel: Create form input based on model

Tags: php, forms, laravel

How can I create a form in Laravel and let Laravel create the form fields with Model name based array of input names such as Post[title], Post[body] . This is what I was doing in Yii but don't know if its possible with Laravel.
Once this is possible I can easily get back the input data as $post->attributes = $_POST['Post'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel there is [Form model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding) to create form based on model but I'm afraid there is no built in creating form based on array.

Comment: This means I can not use array of names such as User[username], User[email] as Laravel will bind to only names matching with field names such as 'email'. Further I would have to populate each model attributes one at a time in the Controller. Is that correctly understood?

Answer (score 0):

When you create for example new article, you dont need use model bind, you must create only a create Form.
My solution is extended FormBuilder form LaraCollection like this, where true it means, that the input is required:

```
  {!! BsForm::bs_open( 'articles.store' ) !!}
  {!! BsForm::bs_text( 'article.title'    , [ 'label' => 'Article title'    ] , true ) !!}
  {!! BsForm::bs_button( 'success' , 'Save' ) !!}
  {!! BsForm::bs_close() !!}
```

Where bs_open automatically generated  form like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='http://test.dev/articles' accept-charset='UTF-8'><input type='hidden' name='_token' value='jCetJsAXCKfQTZ1GV9TZfVt3Ch2WlP8lixeN8gYL'>
```

bs_text generated bootstrap acceptable input type text like this:

```
<div class='form-group'>
<label for='article_title'>Article title</label>
<input class='form-control' name='article_title' type='text' required>
</div>
```

bs_button created nice bootstrap button very easy with extend font awesome icon check:

```
  <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Save</button>
```